# Glide source code, how did reference count in activeResource worked?

Tags: android, android-glide

According to: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/resourcereuse.html

> **Incrementing the reference count**
>
> Each call to `into()` that loads a resource increments the reference count for that resource by one. If the same resource is loaded into two different `Target`s it will have a reference count of two after both loads complete.
>
> **Decrementing the reference count**
>   The reference count is decremented when callers signal that they are done with the resource by:
>
> 1. Calling `clear()` on the `View` or `Target` the resource was loaded in to.
> 2. Calling `into()` on the `View` or `Target` with a request for a new resource.

If the view is created glide load `res` into it, and the view got destroyed and recycled. The count can never decrease and the `ActiveResources` will hold bitmap forever.

What is the trick glide using in reference count?

Comment: You know the Glide project is open source. Just look at the source code

Comment: @ZUNJAE that's very helpful. I hope all people using stackoverflow are like you.

Comment: No problem. I'm always here to help!

Answer (score 0):

It's using WeakReference in the ActiveResource, so it will not cause memory leak.